# How to add values to empty string in for loop?

Tags: java, string, loops, printing, contains

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to append values to the end of a string. In the given code, we are given a dice value and are to print it using "*". For example, a value of five would have two *s in the first row, 1 in the second and 2 in the third. For this, I created a for loop which terminates once the value is reached and tried to append an empty string. I'm not sure how to represent this as dice with a certain number of stars in each row. I've tried other methods, such as finding the total value first and creating a second while loop to add the stars, but can't seem to figure it out.

```
public String toString() {
    String stars = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < value(); i++) {
        if (stars.contains("* * *")){
            //next line
        }
        stars += "*";
    }

    System.out.print(stars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to do it that way. You can create a method to make it print it out. Such as:

```java
static void draw(diceValue) {
    if (diceValue == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < diceValue; i++){
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the main method, you would call for this function(method). Also, I don't see a main method in your code.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    draw(1)
}
```

Note that the 1 is the input parameter or the dice value that you are given.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative method. I actually need to return a String so I was looking for a way to add the star value to the end of an empty string.

Comment: You can use `String.append`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the dice value, here is the program that will help you

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int diceValue = 5;
    String stars = "";
    for(int i=1; i<= diceValue; i++) {
        if(diceValue % 2 != 0) {
            if( i==1 || i%2 == 0 ) {
                stars += "* ";
            }else if(i==diceValue){
                stars += "*";
            }else {
                stars += "\n";
                stars += " *\n";
            }
        }else {
            if( i%2 == 0 ) {
                stars += "* \n";
            }else {
                stars += "* ";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stars);
}

input: 
DiceValue = 5 

Output:
* * 
 *
* *

input:
DiceValue = 4

Output:
* * 
* *
```

This is based on my understanding from your question that you want to print input in the dice format.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same problem without using any library. I found a funny way to do it. This code has limits that it can only print up to 6 dice value. I hope my weird answer still helps.

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int diceValue = 3;
    int[][] diceEquivalentValue = new int[][] {
            {4,5,6}, {}, {2,3,4,5,6}, {6}, {1,3,5},
            {6}, {2,3,4,5,6}, {}, {4,5,6}
    };

    String output = "";
    for( int x = 0; diceEquivalentValue.length > x ; x++ ) {
        output += contains(diceEquivalentValue[x], diceValue) ? "*" : " ";
        output += (x % 3) == 2 ? "\n" : "";
    }

    System.out.print( output );
 }

private static boolean contains( int[] values, int diceValue ) {
    for ( int value : values ) {
        if ( value == diceValue ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output:

```
  *
 * 
*
```